# Copy certain range from all closed workbooks within folder on desktop and paste it to current (master) workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple workbooks in a folder on my desktop. From each of them I want to copy `Range(A14:L26)` and paste it into a (master) table on my current worksheet (Which should be placed in column B:N). Also the copied rows from the different worksheets should be placed underneath each other in a table (that I already created). (In order to be able to visualize them with a pivot chart etc in a second step)

I have two issues with the code I currently have.

1. The FileDialogue pops up but tells me that in the folder where the worksheets I want to extract the data from there were no files that fulfilled my requirement. They are all xlsm Excel workbooks and from the sheet `Important Information` the `Range(A14:L26)` should be copied. How can I make it find the files I am looking for?
2. There are formulars in some of the cells in the range. I want to copy only the value Excel displays and not the formular as the connection doesn't work anymore once the cells are pasted to my current workbook. (Note: The values Excel displays are not only numbers but also names so using the `VALUE()` function on the worksheet doesn't work)

Other than that the code doesn't show any bugs.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PullDataRangeFromClosedFilesOnDesktop()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xSelItem As Variant
    Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xFileName As String
    Dim xSheetName As String
    Dim xRgStr As String
    Dim xBook As Workbook
    Dim xWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim xSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xSheetName = "Important Information" 'CHANGE According to name of sheet 
                                         'that range is supposed to be  
                                         'copied from
    xRgStr = "A14:N26"
    Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With xFileDlg
         If .Show = -1 Then
           xSelItem = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
           Set xWorkBook = ThisWorkbook
           Set xSheet = xWorkBook.Sheets("Tabelle1")
           If xSheet Is Nothing Then

   xWorkBook.Sheets.Add_
   (after:=xWorkBook.Worksheets(xWorkBook.Worksheets.Count))_
   .Name = "Daten zur Auswertung"
           Set xSheet = xWorkBook.Sheets("Daten zur Auswertung")
         End If

            xFileName = Dir(xSelItem & ".xlsm", vbNormal) 
         If xFileName = "" Then Exit Sub
            Do Until xFileName = ""
               Set xBook = Workbooks.Open(xSelItem & "\" & xFileName)
               Set xRg = xBook.Worksheets(xSheetName).Range(xRgStr)
               xRg.Copy xSheet.Range("B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
               xFileName = Dir()
               xBook.Close
            Loop
        End If
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You can add filter(s) to the `FileDialog` like `.Filters.Add "Macros ", "*.xlsm, 1` before you are checking if dialogue even shows. Would that make a difference?

Comment: @JvdV I'm not excactly sure where to add that function as it shows a syntax mistake when I add it right behind FileDialog

Comment: Well, have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.filedialog.filters) for how to put it down correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the data can still not be found

Answer (score 1):

Dear Anna take a look in this code:

```
    Option Explicit

 Sub test()

    Dim strPath As String, strType As String, StrFile As String
    Dim wbLoop As Workbook, wbMaster As Workbook
    Dim Lastrow As Long

    Set wbMaster = Workbooks("Test Loop.xlsm")

    strPath = "C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\ALL Files\"
    strType = "*.xlsm"

    StrFile = Dir(strPath & strType, vbNormal)

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0

        Workbooks.Open Filename:=strPath & StrFile

        Set wbLoop = Workbooks(StrFile)

        Lastrow = wbMaster.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(wbMaster.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        wbLoop.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A14:L26").Copy wbMaster.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Lastrow + 1)

        Workbooks(StrFile).Close SaveChanges:=False

        StrFile = Dir

    Loop

 End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the code but unfortunately the code doesn't do anything. I did add the file path according to where the data is stored.

Comment: The workbooks you loop throught are saved as ".xlsm" or ".xlsx"?

Comment: they are saved as ".xlsm"

Comment: The code get in the Do While? Which is StrFile value ?

Comment: it doesn't show any bugs so the code does run. But it doesn't import the wanted data

Comment: Ok debug the code and ensure that get in the folder and loop the workbooks.

Comment: Nothing happens when doing the single step debugging. Same when running the code. It doesn't show any bugs.

Comment: I'm not sure but isn't the "paste..." line missing in this code? So can it be that the data is only copied but not pasted

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix this would be really appreciated!

Comment: Debug the code and tell me which is the value of StrFile when the code first enter the Do While?

Comment: the value is empty

Comment: it just says StrFile=""

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188434/discussion-between-error-1004-and-anna-von-blohn).